# Как заменить символ в тексте на нужный?

Tags: c, строки

strchr'ом нахожу адрес первопопавшегося(первое вхождение)  символа из массива А. strchr возвращает адрес , и я хочу по этому адресу заменить этот символ , на другой , лежащий в той же итерации , но в другом массиве , но что-то не выходит. Как исправить ?

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        for (;;)
        {

            if ((qwe = strchr(A, num.letter[i])))
            {

                memcpy(qwe, RussianLetters[i], sizeof(char));
            }
            if (qwe == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: А может сойдет что-то типа `*qwe = RussianLetters[qwe-A]`? Ну или для однообразия даже так: `A[qwe-A] =  RussianLetters[qwe-A]`...

Comment: @Elvin, На заметку: `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Comment: дай пример входных данных и желаемого результата, чтобы не играть в угадайку..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меня терзают смутные сомнения (с), что вам нужно ваш `for(;;)` заменить на

```
while(qwe = strchr(A, num.letter[i])) *qwe = RussianLetters[i];
```

Если менять "шило на мыло" - т.е. букву на такую же - можно зациклиться. Во избежание (да и для длинных строк) лучше так:

```
for(char* qwe = strchr(A, num.letter[i]); qwe; qwe = strchr(qwe+1, num.letter[i])
    *qwe = RussianLetters[i];
```

Comment: чтобы работало (сдвигалось, а не на одном месте крутилось): `while((s = strchr(s, num.letter[i]))) *s++ = RussianLetters[i];`

Comment: @Harry, а не зациклится? (imho у ТС та же проблема)

Comment: Может, если он будет менять шило на мыло... Впрочем, сейчас предложу второй вариант.